# How to add "Open link" menu item in contextmenu

Tags: tinymce

I don't find this information in documentation: How to configure this button in `contextmenu` ?

[image]

Screenshot is from official website, so i guess is not impossible :)

Comment: Is that not already in the context menu?  It should only appear when a link is right clicked.

Comment: @MichaelFromin I only have "Link" item when i right click on a link.

Comment: what version of TinyMCE are you using?

Comment: @MichaelFromin i use version 4.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that Open Link option to appear you need to do a couple of things:

1. Load the `contextmenu` plugin
2. Load the `link` plugin
3. Set the `link_context_toolbar` option to `true` (it is `false` by default as documented online https://www.tinymce.com/docs/plugins/link/#link_context_toolbar)

A minimal configuration for this would look like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: [
      "contextmenu link"
  ],
  toolbar: "link",
  link_context_toolbar: true
});
```

***Note***:  The `link_context_toolbar` option first existed in TinyMCE 4.5 so this won't work in older TinyMCE releases.